# ASP Sending Mail

Tags: email, asp-classic

I am a beginner at ASP programming. I am trying to figure out a simple script to send an email. This is my HTML Code:

```
    <form method="POST" action="email.aspx">
    To <input type="text" name="To"/> <br />
    From <input type="text" name="From"/> <br />
    Subject <input type="text" name="Subject"/> <br />
    Body <textarea name="Body" rows="5" cols="20" wrap="physical" > 
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

This is my ASP code:

```
        Dim mail
        mail = Server.CreateObject('CDO.Message')
        mail.To = Request.Form("To")
        mail.From = Request.Form("From")
        mail.Subject = Request.Form("Subject")
        mail.TextBody = Request.Form("Body")
        mail.Send()
        Response.Write("Mail Sent!")
        mail = Nothing
```

I know the set method is no longer supported, I am getting errors with the ASP code, are there any solutions to sending a simple email in ASP? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I would consider using asp.net if your project allows it

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012, is this alright?

Comment: I am just wondering why you use classic asp to send the email, and not  .Net (C# or VB). If you're using VS 2012 you have access to .Net 4.5 even. Take a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the useful link. I am used to working with Apache and PHP, I didn't know to much of the difference between Classic ASP and ASP.NET, you have opened my eyes! Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will only work if CDO or CDONTS is installed and available on your server - though most webhosts that support Classic ASP will make this available.

In VBScript, all objects (i.e. things that aren't numbers or strings) must be assigned using the `Set` operator. It's silly, I know, but this is what you need to do:

```
    Dim mail
    Set mail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    mail.To       = Request.Form("To")
    mail.From     = Request.Form("From")
    mail.Subject  = Request.Form("Subject")
    mail.TextBody = Request.Form("Body")

    mail.Send
    Response.Write "Mail Sent!"
    Set mail = Nothing
```

If your server doesn't have CDO or CDONTS installed then you'll get an error message when you call `CreateObject`, but you haven't listed any error messages in your original question.